# Using jquery.modal on desktop app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, modal-dialog

How do I get npm jquery.modal package working with my node webkit desktop app. I have installed it. How do I include it properly with jQuery? It is not clear in the documentation.

I have tried the below but get errors:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var modal = require('jquery.modal');

var $dialog = $('.my-dialog').modal();
            $dialog.on('click', '.close-btn', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $dialog.modal('close');
            });
            $('.open-btn').on('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $dialog.modal('open');
            });
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Looks like the require failed. This error happens if you were not able to include the library successfully. Please see if there is a failed to load jquery.modal error.